# Como atribuir uma imagem que esta na tela como background de um canvas

Tags: canvas, background

Eu tenho um `canvas` e preciso colocar como `background` dele uma imagem que já está na tela.

Exemplo:

```
<div id="imagens">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="700" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
</div>
```

Eu tenho esta fração de código que coloca uma imagem do site como `backgroud` `document.getElementById("canvas").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.xxxxxx.yyy.br/1005.jpg')";`

Mas eu preciso pegar a imagem que está em `id="imgpreview"` e coloca-la como background do CANVAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta pegares no valor guardado no atributo `src` da imagem.
Exemplo:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var fundo = document.querySelector("#fundo");

canvas.style.backgroundImage=`url(${fundo.src})`;
```

```css
#fundo { display: none; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/re4_9blE4ts/hqdefault.jpg" id="fundo" />
```

Visto que estas a usar o canvas faria mais sentido "pintares" essa imagem diretamente no canvas.
Exemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ =>{
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var fundo = document.querySelector("#fundo");

  context.drawImage(fundo, 0,0);
}, false);
```

```css
#fundo { display: none; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/re4_9blE4ts/hqdefault.jpg" id="fundo" />
```

Comment: Obrigado lazyFox sua primeira alternativa funcionou corretamente.

Comment: E a segunda não? Considere marcar esta questão como solução se não surgirem mais respostas.

Comment: Por algum motivo a 2a não deu certo....

Comment: Secalhar a sua imagem ainda não está carregada quando o código é executado, fiz um pequena alteração no código da resposta veja se faz diferença no resultado final.